# vba to reflect the data of selected columns in listview

Tags: excel, vba

With the below coding, I am able to add data in listview but it is adding all the data from excel. Few of the columns contain sensitive data which I don't want to reflect on listview. Please advise as to how to reflect only selected column's data in listview Eg: column A, Column C, column F, column G.

```
wksSource1.Activate
Set rngData = wksSource1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
If II8 = 1 Then
    For Each rngCell In rngData.Rows(1).Cells
        Me.ListView4.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:=rngCell.Value, Width:=90
    Next rngCell
    II8 = 2
End If
RowCount = rngData.Rows.Count
ColCount = rngData.Columns.Count
For i = 2 To RowCount
    Set LstItem = Me.ListView4.ListItems.Add(Text:=rngData(i, 1).Value)
    For j = 2 To ColCount
        LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=rngData(i, j).Value
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
dim RangeList$()
RangeList= VBA.SPLIT(    Selection.address, ",")
```

==> you can use each of those range address in a for loop